# Python IMAP call

Tags: python, email, imap

I am using the imap library to access my unread messages on gmail and to print out the subjects, is there a way to make sure that the messages being read are still tagged as unread.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use PEEK instead.  For example, something like:

```
typ, data = imap_conn.fetch(uid, '(BODY.PEEK[TEXT])')
```

Comment: Can you tell me where in the docs this function is located: BODY.PEEK[TEXT]) 

So I can see which other options are available.

Comment: @Ali: it's actually part of the IMAP spec: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2060.html -- also see the IMAP PyMOTW blog post which might be useful: http://blog.doughellmann.com/2008/09/pymotw-imaplib.html (though it appears to be down at the moment).

Comment: My code was: b,response2 = M.fetch(e_id,'RFC822')
             msg = HeaderParser().parsestr(response2[0][1])
             print msg['From']

so I should now change the first line to the code you gave?

Comment: @Ali: It looks like you want the headers too, so you can say `fetch(id, 'BODY.PEEK[]')` and it should work.  (The `TEXT` section simply retrieves the email text.)

Comment: For what it's worth, the PyMOTW stuff is now available at https://pymotw.com/2/imaplib/

Answer (score 1):

For info, Yours is an inverse question of this one

- [Parse Gmail with Python and mark all older than date as "read"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296446/parse-gmail-with-python-and-mark-all-older-than-date-as-read)

Use peek, so that you do not affect the message.

But you should also be able to tag the message as unseen.